# show that a horn sentence is preserved under a direct product.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

show that a horn sentence is preserved under a direct product.

If $\varphi$ is a horn sentence and $\mathfrak{A}_i, i \in \text{I}$ is a model for $\varphi$ namely $\mathfrak{A}_i \vDash \varphi$ then $\Pi_{i \in I} \mathfrak{A}_i \vDash \varphi$

is this best done inductively?

Comment: Is a "Horn sentence" a Horn clause whose free variables are all universally quantified?

Comment: @HenningMakholm universally or existentially quantified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any direct need for induction.

**Hint.** Call a wff $\psi$ "smooth" if, whenever you have a variable assignment in each of the $\mathfrak A_i$s that makes $\psi$ true, the pointwise product of the assignment makes $\psi$ true in the product model.

Prove that an *unquantified* Horn clause is always smooth.

Prove that the class of smooth wffs is closed under universal and existential quantification.

Thus (here's room for a bit of induction if you're very formal) a Horn sentence is smooth.

Clearly truth of a smooth *sentence* is preserved by products.

Comment: what does 'wff' stand for?

Comment: @oliverjones: "well-formed formula".